Embed YouTube video where link is to playlist but other videos don't autoplay?
Im embedding a YouTube video on my website.
The video is part of a playlist and when the user clicks to open the video on youtube.com I need it to display as part of the playlist.
Ive done this with the following:
<iframe src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${video.id}${playlistId}`} />

However, when the user is watching the embedded video I don't want the next video in the playlist to auto-play at the end. On my web page, all of the videos are embedded under headings, so the headings are wrong if the video changes.
I tried this https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?playlist=VIDEO_ID&loop=1 but it didnt work.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

If you can obtain a ref to the player, there are specific events when the player loads a new track. The player has a .videoTitle property, self-updating

Also, you can block the next video when the onStateChange event fires. You can call player.pauseVideo()


Do you think that code maybe can work for you?
I tested in your playlist and it is working.
Now you have your video playing in the start and stop in the end. But also with your play list there.
You can Stop, Pause, Start and go to Next and Prev in your playlist.
I hope that now it works for you!
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tutotials</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     
    <script>
      var videoId = "zckH4xalOns";
      var playList = "PL4cUxeGkcC9hL6aCFKyagrT1RCfVN4w2Q";
      var autoPlay = 1; //change to 1 if you need autoPlay or zero to not

      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      
      var player;

      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '360',
          width: '640',
          videoId: videoId,
          playerVars: {
            list: playList,
            autoplay: autoPlay,
            loop: 1,
            rel: 0,
          },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      function onPlayerReady(event) {
         if(autoPlay == 1){
            event.target.playVideo();
         }
      }
      var done = false;

      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          done = true;
        } else if (event.data == -1 && done == true) {
          stopVideo();
          done = false;
        }
      }

      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }

      function pauseVideo() {
        player.pauseVideo();
      }

      function previousVideo() {
        done = false;
        player.previousVideo();
      }

      function nextVideo() {
        done = false;
        player.nextVideo();
      }

      function playVideo() {
        player.playVideo();
      }
    </script>
    
    <div id="player"></div>
    <p>Controls</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="playVideo()">Play!</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="stopVideo()">Stop!</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="pauseVideo()">Pause!</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="nextVideo()">Next!</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="previousVideo()">Prev!</button>
  </body>
</html>


You need to use few URL parameters to control this behavior.
<iframe
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?playlist=VIDEO_ID&loop=0&rel=0&autoplay=0"
  width="560"
  height="315"
  frameborder="0"
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
  allowfullscreen>
</iframe>

Actually, these parameters help you to keep your embedded video under control and when its end, it just stops instead of going to the next video in the playlist.
Moreover, You can use JavaScript for more control with onStateChange event and stops the video by calling player.stopVideo()
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '315',
      width: '560',
      videoId: 'VIDEO_ID',
      playerVars: {
        playlist: 'PLAYLIST_ID',
        autoplay: 0,
        loop: 0,
        rel: 0
      },
      events: {
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      // Stop the video instead of moving to the next one.
      player.stopVideo();
    }
  }
</script>

In that way, you can keep your users focused on your embedded content.

Did you test your code? This doenst open the video on a playlist eg: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zckH4xalOns&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9hL6aCFKyagrT1RCfVN4w2Q&index=2

Based on my above answer I have tweaked the code and it is working fine.
<iframe 
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zckH4xalOns?playlist=PL4cUxeGkcC9hL6aCFKyagrT1RCfVN4w2Q&autoplay=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&autohide=1" 
  frameborder="0" 
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
  allowfullscreen>
</iframe>


Replace 'zckH4xalOns' with your actual video_id and 'PL4cUxeGkcC9hL6aCFKyagrT1RCfVN4w2Q' with your actual id of your playlist.

This also doenst work

What issue you are facing now? can you provide your actual video_id and playlist_id please?

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKnn8TlJ4MA
Playlist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKnn8TlJ4MA&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gF5Gez17eHcDIxrpVSBuVt&index=2

Video ID = DKnn8TlJ4MA. Playlist ID = PL4cUxeGkcC9gF5Gez17eHcDIxrpVSBuVt;

With your code the video doenst load. Instead the YouTube embed says "This video is unavailable"

As I mentioned have you replaced my video_id and playlist_id with yours?

now check my latest posted code. It works perfectly fine and fulfill your requirements

Added the link of my JSFIDDLE (for demo) in my last reply. Please check it must.

Now this is the perfectly working fine code and it runs fine at my end without any errors. I have also added a message in console which says 'Player is ready'.  When the user is watching the embedded video it cannot play the next video in the playlist to auto-play at the end.
<iframe
  id="player"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DKnn8TlJ4MA?autoplay=0&rel=0&controls=1"
  width="560"
  height="315"
  frameborder="0"
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
  allowfullscreen>
</iframe>

<script>
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      events: {
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      // Pause the video to prevent further autoplay
      player.pauseVideo();
    }
  }
</script>


JSFiddle Example
